# Animating Contour maps with FuncAnimation

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I am trying to animate a contour map using the matplotlib function: FuncAnimation. I am not to clear about how the fargs parameter is supposed to be set up, as the documentation isn't very specific regarding this parameter.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Animation with contours matplotlib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124903/animation-with-contours-matplotlib?rq=1)

Comment: Also: [Animating a contour plot in matplotlib using FuncAnimation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9337188/animating-a-contour-plot-in-matplotlib-using-funcanimation)

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried? It is hard to fix code we can not see;) @ali_m Good job on the links!